# WinError 10061 when trying to connect to socket

Tags: python, sockets

In Python, I made a `client.py` and `server.py` with some simple socket code.

**server.py:**

```py
import socket

HEADERSIZE = 10
PORT = 1235
ADDR = "192.168.198.1" # this is my local IP found from ipconfig in cmd

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((ADDR, PORT))
s.listen(5)

while True:
    client, address = s.accept()
    print(f'Connection from {address} established')

    msg = "Hello Client"
    msg = f'{len(msg):<{HEADERSIZE}}'+msg
    client.send(bytes(msg, "utf-8"))
```

**client.py:**

```py
import socket

HEADERSIZE = 10
ADDR = "67.xxx.xxx.xx" # my public IP found from whatsmyip.com
PORT = 1235

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((ADDR, PORT))

while True:

    full = ''
    new = True

    while True:
        msg = s.recv(16)
        if new:
            msglen = int(msg[:HEADERSIZE])
            new = False

        full += msg.decode("utf-8")

        if len(full) - HEADERSIZE == msglen:
            new = True
            full = ''

    print(full)
```

Previously, I had the addresses in both programs set to `socket.gethostname()` because I was working on my computer only. When I sent the client to my friend to test it out with the updated information you see here, I get this error code:

```
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

The same thing happens when I run it on my computer.
I'm very new to sockets / networking, so I apologize if I'm missing something obvious, but I've been having issues with this and any help is appreciated

Comment: `67.xxx.xxx.xx` is usually your internet router's public IP address, which works as gateway for your computer.

Comment: If you are coming from outside the lan, you need to check if your router is using NAT. If so, you will need to forward that port to your pc. [Port forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding)